# how to use paypal payments pro with users Paypal details

Tags: php, curl, paypal

I am developing a payment integration using paypal payments pro using PHP/cURL. The user requires that as well as being able to pay by credit card (which I have implemented and it works by posting the following list of fields: "PARTNER=PayPalUK&VENDOR=HGGQ357J8T&USER=GLD7VF48TH&PWD=D84YDSPXFRA6HK54&TENDER=$tender&TRXTYPE=S&CURRENCYCODE=GPB&AMT=$AMT&CREDITCARDTYPE=$card_type&NAMEONCARD=$name_on_card&ACCT=$card_number&CVV2=$csc&EXPDATE=$expiryDate&ISSUENUMBER=$ISSUENUMBER&COMMENT1=$name_on_card&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=$name_on_card&SECURETOKEN=$SECURETOKEN&SECURETOKENID=$SECURETOKENID") he needs to allow users to be able to pay by entering their paypal login details instead of their card details) I have searched the developers documentation and the only piece of information I can find is that the tender parameter needs to be set to "P". Is the documentation available anywhere? I Assume their must be required fields for users paypal details but what are they called?

Comment: You are not permitted to *ever* solicit a user's PayPal login credentials. It is not supported in that API nor any of their other ones. If you want a user to pay with PayPal, you send them to paypal.com via one of the supported flows.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using now is called Payments Pro.  What are you looking for to enable PayPal payments is [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the Express Checkout API calls very quick and easy for you.

The calls you'll be working with are SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  The SDK includes functional samples for each of those as well as empty templates as good starter files.

You can just open those up and fill in your own values to all of the parameters that are setup for you and it'll handle the rest.